# is it possible to send a custom exception from the server to the client with protobuf-net?

Tags: protobuf-net

I have some customs exceptions that I am using to use the same exceptions in all the layers of the application, so sometimes I need to pass an exception from the server to the client. For example, throw a UniqueValueException, this is interesting to be notified to the client.

However, in the client, when I get the RPCException, I only have a string with the message in the Status.Detail property. But I don't see the way to add the exception as inner exception, for example.

One solution could be to add to the message of the exception a code, for example 0001:[exception message]. I would define a code for each exception and I could parse the message and create the expected exception. But I would like to avoid this if it is possible, and just rethrow the exception.

Is it possible to send custom exceptions from the server to the client?

Thanks.